# Does the maven central repo need to be added to %USER%/.m2/settings.xml?

Tags: maven

I'm trying to build a project with maven and I have a repository I'm pulling packages from which I've configured in the %USER%/.m2/settings.xml file. The problem is it's pulling the packages from that repository but not from the maven central repository.

My question is if I create a settings.xml file and add my own repository to it, do I then also need the maven central repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to configure Maven to retrieve from both a private Maven repository manager (Like Nexus, Artifactory or Achiva) and also download from Maven Central.

Personally I prefer to confgure my Maven repository manager to proxy Maven Central. Within Nexus I create a repository group that combines the Maven Central Proxy with my hosted repositories. In this way a single URL gives me all my project dependencies. This simplifies Maven client configuration.